# State of thread while in run() method (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand multithreading in java. As I was going through the various states a Java thread can be in (new, Runnable, Running, Waiting/Blocked, Dead). I tried to run some simple code to check the states of the thread.

I created a class `MyThread` that extends `Thread` and overrode `run()` method.

```
package com.practice.threads;

public class MyThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        System.out.println("Running Mythread.");
        System.out.println("State of thread : " + this.getState()); // line 2
    }

}
```

Now I have created a simple class to test the states of thread :

```
package com.practice.threads;

public class ThreadStateDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        System.out.println("State of thread : " + myThread.getState());  // line 1
        myThread.start();

    }

}
```

Running this class give the following output :

```
State of thread : NEW
Running Mythread.
State of thread : RUNNABLE
```

The output of line 2 is something I don't understand. When `run()` method of a thread instance is being executed, how can it be in RUNNABLE state? I saw mention of a RUNNING state in a book (SCJP Suncertified Programmer). Should it not show RUNNING?

Comment: [Nope, there is no `RUNNING` state.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) The `RUNNABLE` dictates that: A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.

Comment: Ohh ok! I found RUNNING as a state mentioned in a book (SCJP Suncertified Programmer.) But didn't check Oracle doc though. Thanks!

Comment: Most operating systems distinguish between "runnable" (nothing needs to happen before the thread can be allowed to proceed), and "running" (A CPU actually is executing the thread's code).  But, the Java Language Spec and the the Java standard libraries make no such distinction---maybe because in every practical implementation, thread scheduling is delegated to the operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book has an (easy-to-make) error, the state is `RUNNABLE`, not `RUNNING`. There is no `RUNNING` state, see [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html):

> NEW
>   
> A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
>   
> **RUNNABLE**
>   
> **A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.**
>   
> BLOCKED
>   
> A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
>   
> WAITING
>   
> A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
>   
> TIMED_WAITING
>   
> A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
>   
> TERMINATED
>   
> A thread that has exited is in this state.

*(My emphasis)*

It's just an odd, slightly pedantic name, since technically, it's only running if the OS is running it. But it's "running" from the JVM's point of view.

Comment: So thread scheduler of JVM only picks up a thread according to its algorithm and requests the OS to  run it which makes it 'running' for JVM. But now, it is upon OS to actually run it or not. Could be a redundant comment, but trying to reiterate for confirmation.

Comment: @user3518958: I can't say for sure, but I don't think the JVM has a thread scheduler at all. I would expect it to defer that to the OS entirely. So when you start a thread, the JVM associates it with an OS thread, and then leaves it to the OS to decide when that thread should be scheduled for time on a CPU core.

Answer (score 3):

The JVM doesn't control whether the thread is running or not, the OS does.  The JVM only knows if it asked the OS to run the thread which is what makes it RUNNABLE.